# Elastic Search- Distinct elements from multiple nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created mapping using elasticsearch. Here is the mapping properties

```
"properties": {
         "userPermissions": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "prm": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
           },
         "pSPermissions": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "prm": {
                "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                "type": "string"
                }
            }
         }
      }
```

I want to retrieve overall distinct items from these fields: `userPermissions.id`, `pSPermissions.id`.

I can achieve distinct values of multiple fields under a single `path`. We need to use a script to retrieve terms from multiple fields.

GET /permissions/perm/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count

```
    {
      "aggs": {
        "Parents": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "userPermissions"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "permCount": {
              "terms": {
                "script": "[doc['userPermissions.id'].value,doc['userPermissions.prm'].value]",
                "size": 5000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But I have no idea how to achieve across different paths `userPermissions` and `pSPermissions`. Is it achievable?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the following script:

```
"script": "doc['userPermissions.id'].values + doc['userPermissions.prm'].values",
```

What it does is retrieve all the `userPermissions.id` values and all the `userPermissions.prm` values and then concatenate them into a single array using groovy's `+` operator.

**UPDATE**

Following up on your comment, you can achieve what you want with this script in a similar way as you're already doing for fields under the same path:

```
"script": "doc['userPermissions.id'].values + doc['pSPermissions.id'].values",
```

Comment: I have achieved already what you are suggesting. The problem what I have is, I want concatenated values of `userPermissions.id` and `pSPermissions.id` into a single array.